# iOS Weird Tab Bar Behavior - viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbar

I'm hiding the default apple tab bar as we have created our own. It works fine, but after switching couple of times of tab bar item, the apple default tab bar re-appears and is not hidden anymore. It is kind of random a little. After investigation, we realized that in one view, in between the viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, the properties of the tab bar changed.

For example
At the end of viewWillAppear: tab bar frame (0 431, 320 49), hidden = YES, opaque = NO
At the beginning of viewDidAppear: tab bar frame (320 431, 320 49), opaque = NO

A value of the frame has been changed and the hidden property is lost. Anyone knows what could happen between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear?

Comment: any code u tired....??? And tell me why u using default tab bar if u have created ur own. Please Enlighten more

Comment: I'm not very experienced with iOS. SO I stared with a tab bar template, created a custom one and when our menu items are clicked, we set the selectedIndex value of the apple default one. Otherwise, how could I switch between views without the apple default template? IF you can let me know that, I could probably get rid of the apple default one and it would fix my problem. Thanks for your rapid feedback.

Comment: well there is a way and a pretty easy one. what i do in most of my apps is to create custom buttons instead UITabbar, my designer design the images of those custom buttons in such a way that i works and behaves like the tap bar... what i do is i drop (either from Nib or from code) custom buttons on my view and assign each of them a tag (say 1,2,3,4,5) for 5 tabs . and with the help of one single Actions i gather the tag of the button clicked and using navigation controller i push the appropriate view associated with the tab.. Hope that answers the question :) Let me Know if it worked Cheers

Comment: Thanks BrainStorms, that will work. I'll try that!